# Add class on page zoom. Remove when 100%

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have a fixed navbar. I'd like to add a class of .zoomed to it when the page is zoomed and remove the class when normal size or 100%. I've found this detect-zoom.js plugin:

https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom

…from this thread:

[How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

…that detects the page zoom but I'm a bit clueless when it comes to adding/removing the class. I've managed to get it to add the class when 'zoomed in' but I need to remove the class when at normal 100%. This is what I have which is using bits from the plugin demo:

```
<script src=detect-zoom.js></script>
<script>
    'use scrict';
    var zoomLevel = document.getElementById('zoom-level');
    window.onresize = function onresize() {
        $(".navbar").addClass("zoomed");
    }
    onresize();

    if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
        window.onscroll = onresize;
    }
</script>
```

My css would be:

```
.zoomed{ position: absolute; }
```

Basically I only want the class on the navbar when a page is zoomed. When not zoomed the class should be removed. I'm guessing an 'if' statement but I've tried a few things but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onresize()` function:

```
  // remove zoomed class
  $(".navbar").removeClass("zoomed");

  // 1 is 100%
  var zoom = DetectZoom.zoom();

  // +
  if(zoom > 1)
    $(".navbar").addClass("zoomed in");

  // -
  if(zoom < 1)
    $(".navbar").addClass("zoomed out");
```

(the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jE8Q/))

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Updated here to show the fixed/absolute navbar. http://jsfiddle.net/JsEPq/

Only thing is when I add this code to my scripts.js file it doesn't work. Will try and bug test.